Swapping elements with React Native Reanimated causes flickering
I have a list of items that should swap with neighbours with an animation. Swapping and animation works, but for days I'm trying to solve the issue that there's a very brief flicker of previous order after animation ends.
Here is the working example: https://snack.expo.dev/@episodex/reanimated-swap-flicker
The flicker is more prominent in my real app where the animated component is a lot heavier.
I believe this is because after animation ends and the order is changed in the callback, there is a brief moment when the order is changed but the translationX are not yet reset and it renders this state. Can I avoid somehow this render to prevent flickering? Maybe I should approach the problem differently?
I tried recreating whole list after changing the order and while it solves this particular problem, it introduces several different issues in my real application, so it's not the solution.
The code:
export default function App() {

  const [list, setList] = useState([1, 2, 3])

  const positionsX = useMemo(
      () => list.map((_, index) => makeMutable(0)),
      [list]
    );

  function moveLeft(index: number) {
    // all this should happen without intermediate rerender but it doesn't...
    const item = list[index];
    list.splice(index, 1);
    list.splice(index - 1, 0, item);
    setList([...list]);

    positionsX[index].value = 0;
    positionsX[index -1].value = 0;
  }

  function animateMoveLeft(index: number) {
    positionsX[index - 1].value = withTiming(70, {
      duration: 300,
    });
    positionsX[index].value = withTiming(
      -70,
      {
        duration: 300,
      },
      () => {
        runOnJS(moveLeft)(index);
      }
    );
  }

